# why ajax request success, but it end up in fail call back

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

i am using jquery with ASP.net MVC (backend doesn`t really matter i think)

in javascript, i have a helper function like this

```
postAsync: function (url, data) {
            return $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        }
```

and when i want to interact with server, i will do

```
postAsync("/mycontroler/methodname", {input: value}).done(function(){
  // show success message
}).fail(function(err){
  // show error message
});
```

however, all my ajax request always end up in "fail" callback.
i look into the "err" object, i can see

```
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
```

but why it is end up in error. i debug my controller, it is just fine!!! no exception at all.

any idea?

Comment: Are you sure the backend is giving you correct response? Might be an error in there?

Comment: If your server does not give you json, the status is actually 200/OK but jquery cannot parse json and so it fails. Or it might be an empty answer which is considered as an invalid json content since jQuery 1.9 : http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-ajax-returning-a-json-result-of-an-empty-string

Comment: paste output received in response body into jsonlint.com and make sure it validates.

Comment: it is a void return type from backend...hmm.. it doesn`t return anything.. let me try to have it return something

Comment: think that might help

Comment: yes... that solve the issue.. i return an empty object instead of void.. it works.. great thx guys.

Answer (score 1):

If your server does not give you json, the status is actually 200/OK but jquery cannot parse json and so it fails. Or it might be an empty answer which is considered as an invalid json content since jQuery 1.9 : http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-ajax-returning-a-json-result-of-an-empty-string – Zzirconium 15 mins ago

return an empty object resolve the issue